# Getting %*% using listings for R

Tags: listings, r

I am getting an error when importing R code into latex with the `%*%`  symbol for matrix multiplication. How do I edit the following in order to allow me to add  `%*%` from R to latex output without getting a compilation error.

```
\newcommand{\estiloR}{
  \lstset{ %
    language=R,                     % the language of the code
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,       % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
    numbers=left,                   % where to put the line-numbers
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},  % the style that is used for the line-numbers
    stepnumber=1,                   % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line
                                    % will be numbered
    numbersep=5pt,                  % how far the line-numbers are from the code
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},  % choose the background color. You must add \usepackage{color}
    showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
    showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
    showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
    frame=single,                   % adds a frame around the code
    rulecolor=\color{black},        % if not set, the frame-color may be changed on line-breaks within not-black text (e.g. commens (green here))
    tabsize=2,                      % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
    captionpos=b,                   % sets the caption-position to bottom
    breaklines=true,                % sets automatic line breaking
    breakatwhitespace=false,        % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
    title=\lstname,                 % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting;
                                    % also try caption instead of title
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},      % keyword style
    commentstyle=\color{darkgreen},   % comment style
    stringstyle=\color{red},      % string literal style
    escapeinside={\%*}{*)},         % if you want to add a comment within your code
    morekeywords={*,...}         % if you want to add more keywords to the set
}}
```

This should allow the following code from R to compile without an error.

```
\title{ Title}
\author{Name}
\date{February 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

%########################################################################3
\begin{scriptsize}
\estiloR
\begin{lstlisting}
# Function 1
f_OLS <- function(beta,X,y){
  # Evaluates the loss function
    sum((y - X%*%beta )^2) 
} 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{scriptsize}
%############################################################################

\end{document}
```

Comment: I found this link that could be helpful but I havent had any luck trying to edit the latex to allow for matrix multiplication operator %*%.  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89801/inconsistent-output-for-r-language-operators-when-using-listings-package?rq=1

Comment: Perhaps try removing your `escapeinside` and `morekeywords`, then add `otherkeywords={\%*\%}` instead?

Comment: Welcome. As @LianTzeLim suggested and used here: [R listings operator partially in bold](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62518/)

Comment: @LianTzeLim Thank you it worked. You are such a lifesaver! Thank you for help, you have saved me a lot.